# How can I prevent dojo javascript from being rendered from a custom control with rendered=false?

Tags: custom-controls, xpages

The title of this question may seem a bit confusing, but here is what is happening to me.

First off, I am using Notes/Domino 8.5.3 with UP1.

I have an Xpage with a edit mode custom control inside of it. Within the custom control are various elements using digit.forms. I have tried to set the custom control to be rendered only on edit mode, but even when it is in read mode certain dojo elements are STILL being rendered. To test this I even have set it to rendered=false for the control.

```
<xc:ccEditDocument rendered="false"></xc:ccEditDocument>
```

When I compare the source of the XPage with the custom control as rendered=false VS source of the XPage with NO custom control at all the following differences are encountered:

```
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.6.1/ibm/xsp/widget/layout/layers/xspClientDojoUI.js”></script>
<script type=”text/javascript”>dojo.require(’dijit.form.Form’)</script>
```

and

```
enctype=”multipart/form-data” dojoType=”dijit.form.Form”
```

This is actually causing a  problem for me with IE8 and iFRAME rendering of a PDF (it of course works in all other real browsers).

Is there a way to TRULY have the custom control NOT render the dojo form elements?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

jjtbsomhorst had the fix! It was to add a conditional on the loaded property of the custom control.

```
<xc:ccEditDocument rendered="#{javascript:document1.isEditable()}"
loaded="${javascript:document1.isEditable()}">
</xc:ccEditDocument>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the loaded property and toggle the loading of the element using a viewscope variable. This viewscope var is populated using a url parameter. Because you change the url, and do a full refresh, the loaded property is revaluated. I think this should cause the dojo not to render at unless the dojotype is loaded

Comment: Thanks! The loaded propert was the solution! I simply did the following is this worked for me:   <xc:ccEditProcedure
     rendered="#{javascript:document1.isEditable()}"
     loaded="${javascript:document1.isEditable()}">
    </xc:ccEditProcedure>

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the rendered property of the dojo module in the custom control itself. This will determine then at runtime whether or not the module will be added to the list of resources to be rendered.